# How to run common command for all AppSync calls

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cognito, aws-appsync

We have a concept of Accounts which can be managed by one or more cognito user, and each user can also manage multiple Accounts.

All my DynamoDB items (say Documents) are marked with the relevant accountId - not any userId.

When a user makes an AppSync call they are passing an accountId. I need to verify that they are indeed allowed to use this account.

I see two options.

1. AppSync pipeline - great in theory but I would have to make a pipeline for every single query/mutation so thats not practical. I don't see anything akin to a common entry call.
2. Use a post auth lambda for cognito. That seems to be the potential way to go. The problem I see is that I am not sure how to easily pass the accountId to the signup process and then pass it to the lambda to check. Can I send extra data - perhaps in a header - and will it pass to the lambda?
3. Other ideas?

Comment: If your authorization data (user to accounts list they can manage) is stored say in dynamodb, you can use a pipeline resolver and have a single AppSync function that does the auth  by doing a GetItem to your DDB table and checking for existence.
To use that function, yes you would have to use a pipeline resolver wherever you need to execute it. 
Your second option works as well but it would force you to use a lambda for every resolver. You can forward the request headers to your Lambda, by accessing them from the context using `$context.request.headers`

Comment: I'm in a similar situation in regards to auth and I was thinking of going to AppSync pipeline route. Why do you think it's not practical to have a pipeline resolver for every resolver?

Comment: @Maurice I ended up going that route - does have advantages of more fine grained control. I was thinking not practical because I have to wrap 50 plus existing resolvers in pipeline steps but once I got started it got pretty easy.